# Trying to Run Grunt But Getting Errors and not sure how to fix them

Tags: gruntjs, jslint

I'm currently reading a book on Learning to Program by Steven Foote.  The book is currently talking about automation and is detailing how to use grunt.

I just installed grunt using `npm install -g grunt-cli` succesfully, however I am now running into a error that I'm not familiar with.

When I run grunt I get the following errors:

```
users-mbp:kittenbook user$ grunt
Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
Linting js/prompt.js ...ERROR
[L3:C21] E031: Bad assignment.
'<p>' + projectName = ' ' _ versionNumber +
Linting js/prompt.js ...ERROR
[L3:C22] W033: Missing semicolon.
'<p>' + projectName = ' ' _ versionNumber +
Linting js/prompt.js ...ERROR
[L3:C23] W030: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
'<p>' + projectName = ' ' _ versionNumber +
Linting js/prompt.js ...ERROR
[L3:C26] W033: Missing semicolon.
'<p>' + projectName = ' ' _ versionNumber +
Linting js/prompt.js ...ERROR
[L3:C27] W030: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
'<p>' + projectName = ' ' _ versionNumber +
Linting js/prompt.js ...ERROR
[L3:C28] W033: Missing semicolon.
'<p>' + projectName = ' ' _ versionNumber +
Linting js/prompt.js ...ERROR
[L4:C31] E031: Bad assignment.
'accessed on: ' + currentTime = '</p>';
Linting js/prompt.js ...ERROR
[L4:C31] W030: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
'accessed on: ' + currentTime = '</p>';
Linting js/prompt.js ...ERROR
[L4:C32] W033: Missing semicolon.
'accessed on: ' + currentTime = '</p>';
Linting js/prompt.js ...ERROR
[L4:C33] W030: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
'accessed on: ' + currentTime = '</p>';

Warning: Task "jshint:files" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

`prompt.js` contains:

```js
var userName = prompt('Hello what\'s your name?');
document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello, ' + userName + '!</h1>' +
  '<p>' + projectName = ' ' _ versionNumber +
  'accessed on: ' + currentTime = '</p>';
```

I'm fairly new to grunt so I'm not sure what to do to fix the errors.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a few wrong assignations in `prompt.js`. In a few places you used `=` instead of `+` to concatenate the string.

Replace with the following:

```js
var userName = prompt('Hello what\'s your name?');
document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello, ' + userName + '!</h1>' +
'<p>' + projectName + ' ' + versionNumber +
'accessed on: ' + currentTime + '</p>';
```